# Why does accessing an element in an object using an array as a key work?

Tags: javascript

What do you make of this?

```
var x = {a: 1};         //=> {a: 1}
var y = Object.keys(x); //=> ['a']
x[y]                    //=> 1
```

if `y = ['a']`, `x[y]` is the same as doing `x[['a']]`, right?

```
x[['a']];               //=> 1

x[[['a']]];             //=> 1

x[[[[[[[['a']]]]]]]];   //=> 1
```

Can someone explain what's happening here? Why does this work?

Comment: Probably the unprofessional format of the question is my guess. This is a pretty simple question, though.

Comment: @Qix, I am a srs pro ^.^

Comment: How is it important how long you have been working with JavaScript? Try `` `y.toString()`, this should get you going ...

Comment: @Mithrandir it wouldn't be a surprising observation if I just started learning JavaScript last week.

Comment: Please stop editing *my* question and taking away my identity now.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

@Quentin suggests that property names are automatically converted to strings. Ok, I think he's onto something there, but giving two explicit `arr.toString()` examples doesn't really demonstrate accessing the property of an object using an array. I offered this as an edit to his post. However, he rolled it back.

Anyway, this demonstrates the *implicit* behavior much more evidently, imo.

```
var x = {'a,b,c': 1};

var y = ['a','b','c'];

x[y]; //=> 1
```

Answer (score 13):

Property names have to be strings. If you try to use an array as a property name, it gets its `toString()` method called implicitly. That generates a string containing a comma-separated list of its values.

```
> var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
undefined
> array.toString();
'a,b,c'
```

If you only have one value, then there aren't any commas.

```
> var array = ['a'];
undefined
> array.toString();
'a'
```

Comment: `coma` so many comas. Javascript puts me in a coma sometimes. ;)

Comment: @Quentin, I'm not sure why you rolled back my edit. It actually demonstrates accessing the property with an array. Your answer only offers two examples of `arr.toString()`. Anyway, I've given an answer that shows an actual test case of the behavior you described.

Answer (score -6):

I think it come from 2 facts :

1. The JS engine type as it goes
2. any JS object can be access "like" an array

so your

```
["a"]
```

when used as a key will be "casted" to string, which give

```
a
```

Even

```
[[[[["a"]]]]].toString() == a // true
```

so your

```
x[y]
```

end un as

```
x["a"]
```

Comment: No, because your examples are incorrect. `a` is not a string, to start.